# Finding radius of convergence, odd powers

Tags: calculus, power-series

I am given the following power series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}(x+1)^{2n+1}$$

I need to find the radius of convergence. Based on a solution I read:

$$ a_n =
\begin{cases}
\frac {(-1)^k}{\sqrt k}  & n=2k+1 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases} =  
\begin{cases}
\frac {-1}{\sqrt k}  & n=2k+1 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Is this correct? because I don't understand why $(-1)^k=-1 $ here, since k can be even. I would also like to hear your thoughts on how to solve it, Thanks

Comment: You're right, they confused themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple trick: denote our series by $\sum\limits_{k=3}^{\infty}a_k(x+1)^k$. Then $a_{2k+1}=\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}$ for $k=1,2,\dots$ and $a_{2k}=0$ for $k=2,3,\dots$. Use Cauchy-Hadamard theorem (with $\limsup$ version) to determine the radius of convergence.